# how to translate string in a component using react-i18next?

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

i have a dropdown menu that lists say option1, option2 and option3. i would like to translate these options using react-i18next. I am new to translations and using this framework.

Below is the code,

```
export default class Example extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ParentComponent>
                <button type="button">
                    {this.props.placeholder}
                </button>
                {this.props.values.map(value => (
                    <Item
                        key={value[this.props.value_prop]}
                        value={value}
                        on_select={this.change}>
                        {value[this.props.label_prop]} // i want to 
                        translate this
                    </Item>
                ))}
            </ParentComponent>
        );
}
```

Could someone provide an idea of how to go about this...or help me solve this. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-i18next` contains pretty good documentation and they also offer some [examples](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/example/react/src/App.js).

You basically need to wrap your componenent in a `withTranslation` wrapper and use the `t` props:

```
import { useTranslation, withTranslation, Trans } from 'react-i18next';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

// use hoc for class based components
class LegacyWelcomeClass extends Component {
  render() {
    const { t, i18n } = this.props;
    return <h2>{t('title')}</h2>;
  }
}
const Welcome = withTranslation()(LegacyWelcomeClass);
```

You haven't posted your full component code, but here's how it should look like:

```
class CompClass extends Component {
    render() {
        const { t, i18n } = this.props;
        return (
            <ParentComponent>
                <button type="button">
                    {this.props.placeholder}
                </button>
                {this.props.values.map(value => (
                    <Item
                        key={value[this.props.value_prop]}
                        value={value}
                        on_select={this.change}>
                        {t(value[this.props.label_prop])} // i want to translate this
                    </Item>
                ))}
            </ParentComponent>
        );
    }
}

const Comp = withTranslation()(CompClass);
```